# LFS - Should Glibc be patched in Section 5.7?

Tags: compiling, glibc, patch, lfs

I'm currently working my way through the Linux From Scratch (LFS) book, but I'm a bit confused about when to apply patches.

In [Section 5.7](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter05/glibc.html) the goal is to build `glibc`. The section have a pretty straight forward build instruction, but I noticed in a previous chapter, that I downloaded the patch `Glibc FHS Patch` and there is no mentioning of this patch in the instructions.

Should I patch `glibc` in this section or just follow the instructions ?

NB! Current version of LFS stable is 9.0

Comment: Solution: The patch is not needed in section 5.7, it's needed in section 6.9. There is a note in the beginning of section 5 which says "Several of the packages are patched before compilation, but only when the patch is needed to circumvent a problem. A patch is often needed in both this and the next chapter, but sometimes in only one or the other. Therefore, do not be concerned if instructions for a downloaded patch seem to be missing."

Comment: You can post that as an answer, and (after a timeout) accept it.

Comment: Oh.. I thought i needed reputation to answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The patch is not needed in [Section 5.7](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter05/glibc.html), it's needed in [Section 6.9](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter06/glibc.html).

There is a note in the [general compilation instructions](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter05/generalinstructions.html) which says:

> Several of the packages are patched before compilation, but only when
>   the patch is needed to circumvent a problem. A patch is often needed
>   in both this and the next chapter, but sometimes in only one or the
>   other. Therefore, do not be concerned if instructions for a downloaded
>   patch seem to be missing.

NB! Current version of LFS stable is 9.0